# How to exclude some fields from the document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have the following simple shema:

```
 var userSchema = new Schema({
    name : String,
   age: Number,
   _creator: Schema.ObjectId
  });

  var User = mongoose.model('User',userSchema);
```

What I want to do is create the new document and return to client, but I want to exclude the 'creator' field from one:

```
app.post('/example.json', function (req, res) {
   var user = new User({name: 'John', age: 45, _creator: 'some ObjectId'});
   user.save(function (err) {
      if (err) throw err;

      res.json(200, {user: user});     // how to exclude the _creator field?
   });
});
```

At the end I want to send the new created user without _creator field:

```
{
   name: 'John',
   age: 45
}
```

Is it possible to make without extra find request to mongoose?

**P.S**:It's preferable to make it by

Comment: create a new json object without said field and return it. What's the problem?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Too verbose! There should be some better way.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Another way to handle this on the schema level is to override toJSON for the model.

```
UserSchema.methods.toJSON = function() {
  var obj = this.toObject()
  delete obj.passwordHash
  return obj
}
```

I came across this question looking for a way to exclude password hash from the json i served to the client, and `select: false` broke my verifyPassword function because it didn't retrieve the value from the database at all.

Comment: Try using 
UserSchema.set('toJSON', {
  transform: function(doc, ret, options) {
   delete ret.password;
   return ret;
  }
 });

Comment: Just a beware to anyone copying this code, obj should have a var statement before it, or it will leak a global reference.

Comment: @SirBenBenji You are missing the point. The point is adding a toJSON method wherein you can transform the output. The `passwordHash` property is, itself, irrelevant

Comment: nice solution instead of create new object and dont set all fields except passwordHash

Comment: Is there a way to expand this to conditionally filter fields? For example, admin wants to see an "approved_by" but normal client should not.

Answer (score 63):

The documented way is

```
UserSchema.set('toJSON', {
    transform: function(doc, ret, options) {
        delete ret.password;
        return ret;
    }
});
```

**UPDATE - You might want to use a white list:**

```
UserSchema.set('toJSON', {
    transform: function(doc, ret, options) {
        var retJson = {
            email: ret.email,
            registered: ret.registered,
            modified: ret.modified
        };
        return retJson;
    }
});
```

Comment: or, if your have already underscore/lodash, you can use `_.pick`

      UserSchema.set('toJSON', {
        transform: function(doc, ret, options) {
          return _.pick(ret, 'email', 'registered', 'modified')
        }
      })

Comment: @xerri - where is this documented? i see toJSON, but having trouble finding transform

Comment: @xerri - found it, just got confused, since the docs are under toObject not toJSON ==> http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject

Comment: This is not working in mongoose v4.4.6^ when updating with findByIdAndUpdate. Any help please?

Comment: Not working in v6.0.12 with findByIdAndUpdate or save methods. Tried code here and also from docs for both toObject and toJson. No errors but password field still gets sent to client for post and update. For now I'm handling it in my router with a custom object and res.json() till I can figure out why it isn't working in my schema

Answer (score 18):

Come across your question when I was trying to find a similar answer with pymongo. It turns out that in mongo shell, with the find() function call, you can pass a second parameter which specifies how the result document looks like. When you pass a dictionary with attribute's value being 0, you are excluding this field in all the document that come out of this query.

In your case, for example, the query will be like:

```
db.user.find({an_attr: a_value}, {_creator: 0});
```

It will exclude _creator parameter for you.

In pymongo, the find() function is pretty much the same. Not sure how it translate to mongoose though. I think it's a better solution compare to manually delete the fields afterwards.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Although the others might work, this seems like the correct answer to me. Worked for me.

Comment: This may work in some cases, but not most, because even if you don't want to display the field there's a good chance you want it to operate on in the backend. The problem with this solution and many others like it is that the field in question is never retrieved from the database. If you have other calculated or virtual fields that depend on it, they will not be set properly.

Comment: Bypassing Mongoose seems to be the Recommended Way of doing things in Mongoose these days. Let's one wonder if Mongoose is up to the task at all..

Comment: @nottinhill Extraneous apostrophe!

Answer (score 15):

You can call [`toObject()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject) on the document to convert it to a plain JS object that you can freely modify:

```
user = user.toObject();
delete user._creator;
res.json(200, {user: user});
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, can I define a fields that never return on a Schema level?

Comment: You can hide schema fields by default by including `select: false` in the field's definition.

Comment: This is a much better way to do it than changing the default serialization for all objects.

Answer (score 15):

I would use the lodash utilities [*.pick()*](http://lodash.com/docs#pick) or [.omit()](http://lodash.com/docs#omit)

```
var _ = require('lodash');

app.post('/example.json', function (req, res) {
    var user = new User({name: 'John', age: 45, _creator: 'some ObjectId'});
    user.save(function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        // Only get name and age properties
        var userFiltered = _.pick(user.toObject(), ['name', 'age']);
        res.json(200, {user: user});
    });
});
```

The other example would be:

```
var _ = require('lodash');

app.post('/example.json', function (req, res) {
    var user = new User({name: 'John', age: 45, _creator: 'some ObjectId'});
    user.save(function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        // Remove _creator property
        var userFiltered = _.omit(user.toObject(), ['_creator']);
        res.json(200, {user: user});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 11):

By following the MongoDB documentation, you can exclude fields by passing a second parameter to your query like:

```
User.find({_id: req.user.id}, {password: 0})
        .then(users => {
          res.status(STATUS_OK).json(users);
        })
        .catch(error => res.status(STATUS_NOT_FOUND).json({error: error}));
```

In this case, password will be excluded from the query.

font: https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.8/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#return-all-but-the-excluded-field

Comment: This is a clear and simple solution

Comment: Lovely! Pretty nice

Answer (score 1):

I am using Mongoosemask and am very happy with it.

It does support hiding and exposing properties with other names based on your need

https://github.com/mccormicka/mongoosemask

var maskedModel = mongomask.mask(model, ['name', 'age']); //And you are done.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on the **schema** file itself.

```
// user.js
var userSchema = new Schema({
    name : String,
    age: Number,
   _creator: Schema.ObjectId
  });

userSchema.statics.toClientObject = function (user) {
  const userObject = user?.toObject();
  // Include fields that you want to send
  const clientObject = {
    name: userObject.name,
    age: userObject.age,
  };

  return clientObject;
};

var User = mongoose.model('User',userSchema);
```

Now, in the **controller** method where you are responding back to the client, do the following

```
return res.json({
    user: User.toClientObject(YOUR_ENTIRE_USER_DOC),
  });
```