# Keeping DB data properties private in Node/Mongoose/Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Can anyone tell me the best practices for keeping DB data private and only stored on the DB of a web server?  I'm running a Node/MongoDB/Mongoose/Express stack.

I've got hashed password fields in the db in the User objects and obviously don't want that getting pushed out to the client end when the User data is sent out.

Currently, I'm just manually deleting the properties off of the User objects before I hand it off to Express but that just seems a bit hack-tastic.  Is there a mechanism in Mongoose or Express that lets you delineate private properties that are not supposed to be sent out over the wire and only used internal to the server?

Comment: I'd suggest you override `toJSON` as shown in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11167490/95190

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you retrieve an object from the DB that includes those fields, then they are part of the object.  Deleting them from the object before sending them out is not hack-tastic at all.  Your only options are to:

1. delete the properties before sending it to the response
2. map only the fields you want to a new object and send THAT out with the response
3. use a different query which excludes those properties when dealing with public-facing objects

Comment: I dislike the manual deleting of the properties since, as the complexity of the code increases, the probability that I'll forget to put a delete statement somewhere keeps going up.  

I would much prefer that the Mongoose schema had some sort of mechanism like a private object property that's automatically deleted when the object is exported from Mongoose.

I realize that this would be trivial to implement but it just seems like a common use case and am somewhat surprised that it isn't already baked into Mongoose or Express.

edit - fumble fingers

Comment: I often create my own middleware to expose convenience methods.  You could add your own function to the response object that takes care of that for you.  Like res.sendPrivate(obj); and do your model inspection there.  I am not aware of any tools that clean it for you automatically.

Comment: OK, that's easy enough.  I was mostly looking for confirmation that I'm not just reinventing the wheel before I make my own middleware.  Thanks!

Comment: invent or re-invent and share on github if you do :) Maybe others are looking for that also!