# Return user friend without authentification informations

Tags: node.js

I am trying to build a nodeJS app, with some social feature.
Every user is authenticated with a login/password, and the server returns an authentification token.

Every user can have friends. Here is my User model :

```
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
},
name: String,
tokken: String,
tokkenValidUntil: Date,
friends: [{
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
    }
}],
```

});

At some point, I have to send the user's friend list.
I am using

```
return done(null, user);
```

to serialize the user, and the user firends.

**The problem :** When the user friend is serialised and retured, it contains the token, which is a security issue.

**Do I have to remove the token in every user before sending it back?**

For exemple :

```
user.friends.forEach(function(friendUser) {
     friend.user.token = "";
});
```

**Did I did something wrong in my user & friend class?**

Thanks for your help !

Comment: while qurying the db did you try to put `tokken:0` in the find/findOne query?

Comment: You can override the toJSON method to exclude that information : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160955/how-to-exclude-some-fields-from-the-document

Answer (score 0):

You can try to archive this using only specified fields.

[Mongoose - Model](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find)

ex:

```
// name LIKE john and only selecting the "name" and "friends" fields, executing immediately
MyModel.find({ name: /john/i }, 'name friends', function (err, docs) { })
```