# Mongoose returns default value when excluded in find

Tags: node.js, mongoose

My User Schema is,

```
{
  _id: String,
  name: String,
  status: {type: String, "default": "notverified" }
}
```

In my mongoose query, I need to exclude `status` field from the result.

My Model query is like,

```
User.find({}, {status: false}, function(err, users) {
   // process the error
   if (err) console.error(err);

   // process the result
   console.log(users);
});
```

In the above query, I excluded the `status`, but in the result I get documents with the default value which is defined in the schema. i.e `status: "notverified"`

Even though it is an issue with Mongoose, for quick fix, I tried approaches mentioned here [How to exclude some fields from the document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160955/how-to-exclude-some-fields-from-the-document).

But it doesn't and work, because that queries returns a single document, so `toObject()` will work, but I want to exclude from array of documents, which doesn't have `toObject()` method.

Any other possible working solution(before marking it as duplicate)?

Comment: It's kind of interesting: if you replace `false` by `0`, it _will_ leave out the `status` property. According to [the MongoDB docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/), both `false` and `0` should do the same, so apparently Mongoose changes those semantics.

Answer (score 2):

You misused Mongoose's projection:

```
User.find({}, {status: 0}, function(err, users) {
  // process the error
  if (err) console.error(err);
  // process the result
  console.log(users);
});
```

Comment: No, it's not producing the expected output, same result with this approach too.

Comment: Strange, it works for me. Can you try with a different syntax ?
User.find({}).select("-status").exec(yourCallback);

Comment: Sorry, FYI, in the query I'm finding with `status: 'verified'`, not empty query. Just for simplicity, posted here empty query

Comment: I don't understand. Just do `User.find({"status":"verified}).select("-status").exec(yourCallback);` instead

Comment: Damnit, can you try to do your queries in the mongo shell ?

Comment: Chill out mate, people here take the time trying to help you.
I obviously read your question and corrected your error, that works for me. Code I gave you is not Mongoose specific, that's why I asked if you could try in the Mongo shell.
Last thing you can try before I wish you good luck, make the "status" field not returned by default in your schema `status: {type: String, "default": "notverified", "select": false}`

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't do it. Because if I do so, i can't fetch the value of status ever. This is critical issue with Mongoose. I don't know why they didn't fix it yet. In my question I clearly mentioned, `Mongoose query..`

Comment: Well, I use the `select` method in production and have no problem with it... If you think it really is Mongoose's fault, open an issue on their github and let's see what happens. Mongoose is definitely not bug-free.