# Censoring MongoDB fields with Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am thinking on the best way to censor some MongoDB fields using Mongoose ORM. Having

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  last_name: {
  type: String,
  select: false,
  }
});

userSchema.virtual('last_name_initial').get(function () {
  return this.last_name.substr(0,1).toUpperCase();
});
```

Wouldn't do it because `last_name` is set as `select: false`, Obviously I don't want to send back `last_name`

Comment: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1195

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify `{select: false}` on any field in the schema, the field is excluded in queries by default. So, in this case, your virtual field will only work objects which have been queried like this:

```
User.find().select('+last_name').exec(function (err, users) {

    //The virtual field should be available here.
    console.log(users[0].last_name_initial);
});
```

If you want the virtual field to always be available without having to explicitly include the field for selection then it would be better to use another approach than `{select: false}`.

One way you could exclude the field by default is by overriding the `toJSON` method ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11167490/2043580) had the same problem as you)

```
userSchema.methods.toJSON = function() {
  var obj = this.toObject()
  delete obj.last_name
  return obj
}
```

NOTE: With this approach, you should also set the option {virtuals: true} for toJSON.

```
userSchema.set('toJSON', {virtuals: true});
```

Comment: Trying your answer didn't work as overriding toJSON didn't include the virtual fields, so I have ended up removing the virtual fields and doing:
`userSchema.methods.toJSON = function() { let obj = this.toObject(); obj.last_name_initial = obj.last_name.substr(0,1).toUpperCase();delete obj.last_name;return obj;};`

Comment: Yeah... that is good as well... Will check about the virtuals option for toJSON