# How to not save a field in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to integrate `MongoDB` and `elasticsearch` in an Application using `mongoosastic` and it requires one field to be stored in `elasticsearch` and not in `MongoDB`. How to achieve it?

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160955/how-to-exclude-some-fields-from-the-document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was as easy as inserting `select: false` in the `Mongoose Schema`.