# Mongoose restrict returned data to model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the most basic Mongoose schema possible. Something like this :

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

ConfigSchema = new Schema({
  title: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Config", ConfigSchema);
```

If I get data (using the `find` function) from this collection using this model, I get the whole object.
Call:

```
Config.find(function(err, configs) {
  if (err) res.send(err);
  res.json(configs);
});
```

Data returned :

[image]

What I thought was that Mongoose would validate the fetched data against the model to only return the data that fits the model so in this case, only the title for the element. I know I can use the `strict` attribute on Mongoose to enforce the model on save but what I am looking for is a way to only get the Modeled data.

Is there something I am missing here or am I just looking at the wrong tool for what I wish to accomplish. 
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11160955) which seems to do what I am looking for but I am not looking to overwrite the Mongoose schema simply to enforce it when I get data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there's nothing built-in for querying but you can easily implement your own [pre-middleware](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre)

```
ConfigSchema.pre('find', function() {
    this.select(Object.keys(ConfigSchema.tree));
});
```

This will generate following query when you run your `Config.find`:

```
configs.find({}, { projection: { title: 1, _id: 1, __v: 1, id: 1 } })
```