# Mongoose Remove Fields not on schema on read/find

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a schema:

```js
const LinkSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String },
    style: { default: "icon", type: String },
});
```

And a document already in mongoDB with potentially many old fields.

```js
{
   "name": "abcLink",
   "oldThing1": true,
   "oldThing2": "oeunth",
   ....
   "oldThing100": "hi",
}
```

I want `link.findOne({ name: "abcLink" })` to return

```js
{
   "name": "abcLink",
   "style": "icon"
}
```

Currently, I get

```js
{
   "name": "abcLink",
   "oldThing": true,
   "style": "icon"
}
```

How can I have `strict` reads to get back a filtered object where any fields not defined in the schema are not returned?

Because we have 30+ active fields and many inactive fields, it's important that we can define the schema once and then automatically filter the results.  We do not want to duplicate the valid or invalid fields in multiple places.  Note: Using a function like `Object.keys` on the schema to get an array of the valid fields and using that to filter is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: The problem is isNew is a reserved word which makes it difficult to find an answer.

Comment: @SuleymanSah I renamed `isNew` to `oldThing`.  The result is the same.

Comment: after that, add that filed to schema and set its select option to false. Now that field will not be retrieved

Comment: The idea is to delete fields from the schema that a no longer used so they no longer get saved in the database or selected.  I think that would make them keep getting saved which I don't want to happen either.  (Currently, they are correctly removed on save with `strict: true`.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to exclude some fields from the document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160955/how-to-exclude-some-fields-from-the-document)

Comment: Loren, did you check my new answer? I guess that is what you wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the `toJSON` method  using the transform function like this so that it doesn't have any fields not in the schema.

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const LinkSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String },
  style: { default: "icon", type: String }
});

var schemaFields = Object.keys(LinkSchema.paths);

LinkSchema.set("toJSON", {
  transform: function(doc, ret, options) {
    let result = {};
    Object.keys(ret).map(key => {
      if (schemaFields.includes(key)) {
        result[key] = ret[key];
      }
    });

    return result;
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Link", LinkSchema);
```

Update as @Loren mentioned in the comments, for the nested objects we can use `Object.keys(LinkSchema.tree)` instead of `Object.keys(LinkSchema.paths)`.

Comment: If you have a nested object paths includes the full path ie `details.something` so that results in too much getting removed because `details` which is a key on `ret` doesn't get copied over. Using `const schemaFields = Object.keys(LinkSchema.tree);` fixes it for me because then schema fields contains `details` rather than `details.something`.

Comment: @Loren for nested objects you may need some additions, but this is the best approach you can find I think.

Comment: If you change it to Object.keys(LinkSchema.tree), instead of Object.keys(LinkSchema.paths).  It works great with nested trees as well as without.

Comment: @Loren hmm super, I update the answer with this info. I appreciate if you can mark as answer and upvote. I really tried hard for this:)